# copy the action from button A to button B

Tags: jquery

If I have a code like :

```
<a href="" id="reset_all_filters" >Reset All</a>

<form>
<input type="reset" class="buttonclear" onClick="BF.reset()" value="Reset All" />
</form>
```

How can I trigger the reset input type in the form using jQuery, when user click on the "reset_all_filters" link ?

Comment: Please show some relevant code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Where are you stuck then???

Comment: `$("#reset_all_filters").click(function() { $("input[type=reset]").click(); });`

Comment: You could set element as a button type reset and use `form` attribute, unfortunately, as often, IE doesn't support it

Comment: @gillesc your code redirects to homepage

Comment: @gillesc , adding e.preventDefault(); actually works on your code as well.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#reset_all_filters").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#reset_all_filters").on("click", function()
{
    $("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Then you should either add an `e.preventDefault();` to the JS or set the `href` attribute of the `reset_all_filters` link to `#`.

Comment: yeah, adding e.preventDefault(); works.. thanks... actually @Shail got it right at the first place.